# How to insert an element to a collection field in MongoDB using Spring Data scalably?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Suppose we have a MongoDB collection called Threads where it has a field of typed collection for replies to the original post.

When the user hits the reply, we would want to create a new post instance and append it to the replies field. It can be easily done as follows:

```
var thread = threadRepository.findById(threadId);
thread.getReplies().add(post);
threadRepository.save(thread);
```

But a question arises, is this solution scalable? What if there are 1 million replies to that thread?

**My main question is:**
Will they all be loaded in memory?

If yes, wouldn't it be a waste if all we wanted to do is create a new reply? What is the recommended solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the replies are nested within the `thread` document, then yes, they will be loaded into memory unless you explicitly specify which fields to load via `@Query(fields=...)`

In order to modify the Document without having to load it into memory consider an update instead of a replace operation.

```java
Update update = new Update().push("replies", post);
template.updateFirst(query(where("id").is(thread.id)), update, Thread.class)
```

With `$push` it's possible to append an item to an array. Please see the MongoDB reference [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-a-value-to-an-array) for more details.

In case the intention is to potentially store millions of replies that way, then please keep at least the Document max [size limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit) in mind and consider a feasible loading strategy.